# How to convert RGBA colors (with opacity) to hex/solid colors?

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I have a web GUI, works and everything, except this: the rainbow background mode; there is an option to enable opacity and disable opacity, along with the automatically-changing colors.

```js
function toggleOpacity(){
    opacity = !opacity;
    // This is where I am troubled
    if (opacity){
      ui.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30})'; // if opacity is true, then set the color with the opacity
    }else{
      ui.style.backgroundColor = '#D9D9D9'; // else solid color
    }
}
```

Comment: @user229044 I am showing what the backgroundColor options are???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to extract "`r`, `g`, `b`, and `a`" from your color in `rgba` color coding. Then, you can use the following function to convert it to hex color coding. Also, if `opacity = false`, you can change `a = 1` so that you can again use the same function.

```
function RGBAToHexA(r,g,b,a) {
  r = r.toString(16);
  g = g.toString(16);
  b = b.toString(16);
  a = Math.round(a * 255).toString(16);

  if (r.length == 1)
    r = "0" + r;
  if (g.length == 1)
    g = "0" + g;
  if (b.length == 1)
    b = "0" + b;
  if (a.length == 1)
    a = "0" + a;

  return "#" + r + g + b + a;
}
```